# What does I1101 mean in pylint

Tags: pylint

What does `I` mean in pylint? I haven't seen an error message that starts with `I` before.

Based on https://docs.pylint.org/en/1.6.0/tutorial.html, `I` is not included in the following list

```
  * (C) convention, for programming standard violation
  * (R) refactor, for bad code smell
  * (W) warning, for python specific problems
  * (E) error, for much probably bugs in the code
  * (F) fatal, if an error occurred which prevented pylint from doing
```

It's related to a C++ extension.

```
Consider adding this module to extension-pkg-whitelist if you want to perform analysis based on run-time introspection of living objects. (c-extension-no-member)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it in the source code (Pylint version 2.6.0):

```
"I1101": (
    "%s %r has no %r member%s, but source is unavailable. Consider "
    "adding this module to extension-pkg-whitelist if you want "
    "to perform analysis based on run-time introspection of living objects.",
    "c-extension-no-member",
    "Used when a variable is accessed for non-existent member of C "
    "extension. Due to unavailability of source static analysis is impossible, "
    "but it may be performed by introspecting living objects in run-time.",
```

And also a list of the error codes [here](https://codedb.app/docs/pylint-messages.html?highlight=i1101) including the "I".

As for what `I` means:

1. if you can reproduce the message then i suggest generating Pylint reports then prints a list with all the error categories of your result. Hopefully the `I` category too.
   To enable reports, when you run Pylint simply add the flag `-rn` or `--reports=y`
2. [This](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/2.6/technical_reference/c_extensions.html) documentation might help you understand more, so you could just disable this error if you wish to.